# jQuery & Bootstrap in ASP.NET Core project

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I messed up my configuration of bootstrap and jquery inside my project and now these tools won't load properly.

What is happening is that bootstrap is loading before jquery and so, I get the following error messages when I check the console and the network options inside the browser:

**Console**

[image]

**Network**

[image]

**Important mention:** Inside my project I (almost) never declare the source of javascript inside a view, either for bootstrap or jquery. This because, at least in ASP.Net, it appears to be a "framework", to call it someway, that loads these for the entire project, and so, I only declare particular javascript files that I personally add.

I'm deducting that the file in charge of loading JQuery and bootstrap is _Layout.cshtml

[image]

**Problem:** What I'm trying to do is to make jquery and bootstrap to work again in my project. If the solutions is to make jquery load before bootstrap, I don't really know where to make the change. I believe it might be inside _Layout.cshtml but for the look of it, Jquery is been declared before bootstrap, so I don't know where to make the change.

I thank beforehand to anyone who can give me an idea on how to do this!

Thanks

Comment: You see in "Network" you load jquery.js and then jquery.3-2-1.min.js. Probably you have another files, which loads jquery.

Comment: oh, yeah, that was because of a test I made (I put a reference on purpose inside the Index view to see if it will load), I already discarded **jquery.3-2-1.min.js** and the problem still persist.

Comment: Test it again: remove all: jquery.js and bootstrap.js. And see if they loads or not.

Comment: all done, run it again and updated the screenshots.

Comment: Hit ctrl+f5 you have libraries loading from memory.

Comment: @DonaldPowell Thanks, hitted ctrl+f5 and updated pictures

Comment: Test what happens if in code you load bootstap, then jquery. You have to be sure if you try to fix right file. May be you changed some setting for loading frameworks somewhere else in ASP.

Comment: You mean inside a view? Right now in the view I'm using to get the screenshots I don't have any reference to bootstrap or jquery. I believe that if I add them, they will be shown as duplicated in the console. I do believe something changed in my settings when I load the framework but no idea where. Thanks for your replies! Hope I can fix this soon.

Comment: Make sure the /lib/kendo-ui/js folder is present and all the kendo scripts are in the folder. Likewise for kendo css.

Comment: Also check App_Start/BundleConfig.cs scripts and css are bundled here.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work

To keep it clean, I deleted the references to kendo.ui that I had in the _Layout.cshtml, both in the Development and Staging/Production enviroment.

I don't really know how the fail load of these sources crashed my javascript since they weren't been called/used in the solution, but it's all ok now!

Thanks all